# Show objects in one array that are not in another

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 `arrays`, let's call them `List1` and `List2`. I want to display only the objects in `List1` that are NOT in `List2`

`List1` looks like this:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: banana
    },

    {
        id: 2,
        name: apple
    }
]
```

`List2` looks like this:

```
[
    {
        id: 2,
        name: apple
    }
]
```

How can I accomplish this in `AngularJS` / `Javascript`?

Comment: What have you tried so far. Also, those aren't arrays. I assume that you meant to use `[]` rather than `{}`?

Comment: numerous ways to approach this in angular...is somewhat dependent on use case. Please provide more details, code example would help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your ids are unique, this is quite easy to do:

First you need to collect the ids in List 2. [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is a good candidate for this.

```
var L2_ids = List2.map(function(el2){return el2.id})
// [2] in your example
```

now we can filter List1 based on whether each element's ID is in the L2_ids list. [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) will do nicely:

```
var diffList = List1.filter(function(x){return L2_ids.indexOf(x.id)===-1})
// [ {banana object} ]
```